синонимизировать и/или связать метки: [замыкания], [callback], [scope], [область-видимости]
в связи с слабой освещенностью темы замыканий, предлагаю докинуть в её группу (замыкания, замыкание, closure):

scope в качестве синонимома(как неотъемлимую часть механизма), либо привязать с легким рерайтом описаний.
возможно callback как полноценный синоним(хотя описание там есть и прям тематически отделяющее)
хотя бы привязать к ним область-видимости(как сущность, которой замыкания и ~манипулируют)




метка
синонимы
описание
кол-во вопросов




замыкания
замыкание, closure
+
119


scope
-
-
41


callback
-
только короткое
264


область-видимости
-
-
77


JS(для сравнения освещенности)
JavaScropt
+
68k




Пока не вижу причин для создания синонимов:

Замыкание - это методика/механика реализации обёрток для функций. Размытое понятие, используемое почти всегда только в академических целях.
Scope (набор) - это это не только область видимости, но может быть и область времени жизни сущностей, в общем понятие про объединение группы сущностей в группу для какой-то цели.
Callback (обратный вызов) - просто обратный вызов. Это может быть событие. Это может быть асинхронная операция, что угодно, что через какое-то время запустит вам какой-то метод.
Область видимости - это разновидность скоупа, как я выше писал, частный случай.

Итого из всего перечисленного, я бы мог предложить скоуп и область видимости объединить в пользу последней, но для того чтобы определить возможность такого объедниения, надо изучить большинство вопросов в метке и убедиться, что замена метки не испортит их контекст. Остальные же метки просто про разное, а за уши синонимы не притягивают.

+1 за развернутый ответ
